# Median of the mean/max of an iid sample of exponential variables

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

I would like to know if one can obtain a simple analytic expression of the median of $T_n$ defined by
$$ T_n = \frac{\overline X_n}{X_{(n)}},   $$
where $\overline X_n$ is the empirical mean and $X_{(n)}$ the maximum of an iid sample of exponential random variables. The value does not depend on the parameter so we can take an exponential of parameter $1$ WLOG. I calculated the density of $T_n$, it is
$$   \frac{n!}{n^{n-1}}  \ \frac{ I_{n-1}(n t-1)}{t^n} , \ t \in \Big[ \frac 1 n,1 \Big]  $$ 
where $I_{n-1}$ is the density of the Irwin-Hall distribution (the sum of $n-1$ independent uniform rv on $[0,1]$),
$$  I_{n-1}(t) =  \frac n {2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \text{sgn}(t-k) \frac{(-1)^k (t-k)^{n-2}}{k! (n-k)!}, \ t \in [0,n-1],  $$
(sgn is the sign function) but I couldn't calculate the median from this. I'm sure there is a more clever thing to do, but I can't find it. Thanks for any help.